# Saints Row The Third doesn't start in DX9 mode but does in DX10/11 with lag

Tags: saints-row-the-third

I have a very annoying problem with Saints Row The Third. Whenever i open the launcher and click the DirectX9 option it crashes without even starting up, while the DirectX10/11 one starts without any problems. That wouldn't be a problem if my computer could run it smoothly, but sadly it doesn't. the only way I can get it to run well (barely) is on minimum settings and with a resolution of under 800x600. I'm really thinking the DirectX9 version would run better, but i cant even test that.
My specs are:

- CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo 3.0GHz
- GPU: Intel G45/G43 Express Chipset
- RAM: 4096MB
- OS: Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit

  If there's anything I've missed I'll edit this question, thank you.

Comment: You might get better performance with DirectX 9, but the biggest problem is your GPU. It's simply not suited for gaming at all.

Comment: @Nolonar I know but i get by till i manage to upgrade it.

Comment: What resolution are you trying to run the game at?

Comment: I tried the smallest ones, went from 800x600 to 640x480 and it still ran insanely slow